# How to set text inside Text componenttext content not to exceed its width and height in QML

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a `Rectangle` and on top of it there is a `Text` item. Text contained in the latter does exceeding its boundary.

Here is my code:

```
Rectangle{
    width: 100
    height: 100
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    color: "lightblue"

    Text{
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        text: "hi hello how are you. good how do you dosdfskdjgbksajgsjdfsjadfsad \n"+
              "sdfvbjsdkfjsbdvfsd sjkdbfvskdbfvskdbvs,dv jskbdvksdbvasd \n"+
              "sajbfwkbedcv klanfuoigbefhbsdaf csa djsdagfbksdjbfvsadkjvABEGFW\n"+
              "JGBGFWJAHGRJWEKHYJGWKGBFWHE  gofdgfdfgdf"
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [documented](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#wrapMode-prop):

> Text.WordWrap - wrapping is done on word boundaries only. If a word is too long, contentWidth will exceed a set width.

That's what's happening with your text. You probably want to use `Text.Wrap`:

> Text.Wrap - if possible, wrapping occurs at a word boundary; otherwise it will occur at the appropriate point on the line, even in the middle of a word.

Combined with some eliding, the text will fit perfectly within the `Rectangle`:

```
elide: Text.ElideRight
```